# Setting the size of an image in an ASP.Net TreeView

Tags: asp.net, treeview, size, image-resizing

How do you set the size of an image in an ASP.Net TreeView?

We tried to set the size like this but the images are showing in full size:

```
<asp:TreeView 
    runat="server"
    DataSourceID="KnowledgeAcademySiteMap">

    <RootNodeStyle ImageUrl="/Images/book.png" Height="32px" Width="32px" />
    <ParentNodeStyle ImageUrl="/Images/book.png" Height="32px" Width="32px" />
    <LeafNodeStyle ImageUrl="/Images/book.png" Height="32px" Width="32px" />
</asp:TreeView>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That height and width is applied to the tree view node, **not to the image**, that explains why the image size doesn't change.

You can either:

1. Change the size of the image using photoshop, .NET Paint etc or
2. Apply a CSS style rule to the images contained in the tree view, example:

**CSS:**

.treeView img
{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
}

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:TreeView CssClass="treeView" ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I made a copy of the image in a smaller size. It would be nice if they would add a width and height attribute that I can use in the markup.

Comment: If you have [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net) installed, you can just add ?width=32 to the image URLs.